# samba share access from windows to ubuntu with Microsoft account

Tags: networking, samba

I want to access a samba share folder hosted on my ubuntu machine from my windows machine using file explorer. If I create a local windows account using the same username as the ubuntu machine it works. But it does not work using my main Microsoft account login, I end up getting "You do not have permissions to access \192....."

How might I make that happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This Ubuntu Tutorial for installing and setting up Samba works here

[Samba Tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview)

> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt install samba
>
> We can check if the installation was successful by running: whereis
> samba
>
> The following should be its output:
>
> samba: /usr/sbin/samba /usr/lib/samba /etc/samba /usr/share/samba
> /usr/share/man/man7/samba.7.gz /usr/share/man/man8/samba.8.gz
>
> Now that Samba is installed, we need to create a directory for it to
> share:
>
> mkdir /home//sambashare/
>
> Now that Samba is installed, we need to create a directory for it to
> share:
>
> mkdir /home//sambashare/
>
> Since Samba doesn’t use the system account password, we need to set up
> a Samba password for our user account:
>
> sudo smbpasswd -a username   **<---- This can be a local account**  even though the Windows OS has a Microsoft Account.
>
> On Ubuntu: Open up the default file manager and click Connect to
> Server then enter:
>
> smb://ip-address/sambashare
>
> On Windows, open up File Manager and edit the file path to:
>
> \ip-address\sambashare
>
> Note: ip-address is the Samba server IP address and sambashare is the
> name of the share.
>
> You’ll be prompted for your credentials. Enter them to connect!

This allowed me to connect Windows 10 / 11 to Ubuntu 20.04.

Read the entire tutorial I posted and follow it carefully. I printed it out and added notes as I went.

Comment: Yes I've done this and had no luck. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I have tested this article and method. Perhaps some other issue with your machine?  Samba has been around for a  while.